# C# HttpResponse returns statuscode 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: c#, httpresponse, http-status-code-406

I have created an Azure Function which connects to an API. This is the code:

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponse> RunProduction(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
ILogger log)
{
    _log = log;
    API_URL = @"{API_URL}";
    BEARER_TOKEN = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("{ENV_NAME}");
    if (BEARER_TOKEN.Equals("")) throw new Exception("Bearer token could not be retrieved");

    var response = req.HttpContext.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.StatusCode = 200;
    response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    //This is where the API will be called.
    //The method is not changing anything in the response (yet)
    response = await ExecuteMethods(req, response); 

    return response;
}
```

I am testing the Function locally with Postman. In Postman, I have the following headers:
[image: Postman header information]

Every time I test the Function, I receive a 406 Not Acceptable. This even happens when I comment the line where the method `ExecuteMethods()` is being called.
Any ideas how I can get rid of the 406-error and get my 200-statuscode again?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever add the bearer token to the request. Also the changes you make the the response object before you execute the method doesn't do anything, and can be removed.

Comment: So, that bearer token is used somewhere in the ```ExecuteMethods()``` method, so it is definitely being used. Also, the code shown above is just for testing purposes. I know it doesn't do anything, but it still returns the 406-statuscode. Also, with specifying the ContentType, it returns an error.